# How can I properly shutdown a Linux machine from terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, shutdown, poweroff

What should I type to safely shutdown a Linux computer from terminal?

---

My circumstance is: 
I'm using "Raspberry Pi Zero W" over VNC (and SSH). I was able to shutdown it by GUI, but now I press the "Shutdown" button and nothing happens. 
The "Raspberry Pi Configuration" app doesn't work neither, but it is not a big problem for me since "sudo raspi-config" works fine. I love the terminal :) 
(The OS is "Raspbian Stretch", but I'd prefer a universal way if possible, since I also use other Linux-based OSes. That's why I'm posting this question here instead of Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange.)

Comment: I use `shutdown -h now`. This certainly works on Debian-based systems, but I don't know how universal it is.

Comment: Your answer works on most Linux distributions, Mac OSX, and Raspberry Pi. It is necessary to be root while executing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sudo reboot` and `sudo poweroff` will reboot and shut down most Debian flavors.

You can also use `sudo shutdown -h now` to shut down the device and `sudo shutdown -r now` to reboot the device.

All this can be done through CLI.

Comment: Both `sudo poweroff` and `sudo shutdown -h now` worked fine on Lubuntu 16.04.1, Linux Mint 18.3 and Raspbian Stretch. Thanks!